# php pagination full list of pages instead of small list with next and prev

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

My pagination code shows a full list of pages like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 but i want it to show Prev,1,2,3,4,5,Next instead how can i do this with this code

```
if($tot>$perq) {
    $output.="<div class='pagenation'>";
    for($i=0;$i<($tot/$perq);$i++) {
        $j=$i+1;
        if($pg==$i)
            $output.="<a href='".get_permalink()."?pg=$i' class='button active'>".$j."</a>";
        else
            $output.="<a href='".get_permalink()."?pg=$i' class='button'>".$j."</a>";
    }
    $output.="</div>";
}
```

Comment: lots of different javascript  plugins available for doing this ...easy to find in web search

Comment: how is this related to `jquery` and `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from a site I am working on. The keywords are 'previous_posts_link' and 'next_posts_link', which together with the $arg 'posts_per_page' will paginate for you.

Hope it helps.

```
<?php
    the_content();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'bonsai','posts_per_page' =>12,'paged' => $paged);
    $myposts = query_posts($args);
    ?>
    <span id="tree-list-span">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>The Bonsai</legend>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li class="main_bonsai_list_item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->id);?>">
            <span  class="grower_name"><?php the_title();?></span><br/>
            <span  class="grower_name">
            <?php 
                $attr = array(
                    'id' => "link-".$post->ID,
                    'style' => 'max-width: 120px',
                );
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id,'bonsai-list-thumb',$attr);
            ?>
            </span><br/>
            <?php $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);?>
            <?php $grower = $custom["tree_grower"][0];?>
            <span class="grower_name"><?php echo $grower;?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; 
    ?>
    </ul>
    <span id="page_links">
    <?php
    previous_posts_link( '&laquo;' ); 
    next_posts_link( '&raquo;', $myposts->max_num_pages );
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    </span>
    </fieldset>

    <?php
?>
```

Comment: Your pagination is for a WordPress post loop am trying to edit a custom plugin